# What happened to Team Foundation Server on http://tfs.visualstudio.com/

Tags: tfs

More than a three years ago I uploaded some code to online free TFS at http://tfs.visualstudio.com/ (as I remember it was free for up to five team members).

I forgot about the code since then and today I wanted to access it, but it sees that http://tfs.visualstudio.com/ is not available. So, I am not sure if this is the right question for stack-overflow, but does someone knows what happened to the code that people uploaded here, is it moved somewhere else or is it lost forever? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS online previous name is Visual Studio Team Service(VSTS). On September 10, 2018, Microsoft renamed Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) to **Azure DevOps Services**.

VSTS features are now separate services:

[image]

For the url's change. We've moved to the new dev.azure.com domain name as the primary URL for new organizations. (Specifically, it's `https://dev.azure.com/[your organization name]`.)

If you want to change your URL to be based on dev.azure.com as the primary, an organization administrator can change this from the organization settings page.  We will also support redirects from visualstudio.com URLs so there will not be broken links.

For more information about this change, see [Introducing Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-devops/).

---

Even with the old url, you are using the wrong type.

It should be  `https://[your organization name].visualstudio.com`, also give a try with the new kind url `https://dev.azure.com/[your organization name]`.

Make sure that's the right organization and project you have selected. Microsoft will not 
initiative to delete your data.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, in the end I have just forgot to type the right address, I have found the code at https://[your organization name].visualstudio.com as you said.